# How to select a single child element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

Using jQuery how do I select a single child element? I've looked at the Traversing API and know I can select all the immediate children `img` elements like this:

```
$(this).children('img');
```

And to select the first child `img` element I could use a subscript like this:

```
$(this).children('img')[0];
```

But I guess I'm kind of surprised I can't do this:

```
$(this).child('img'); // no subscript, returns single element
```

Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No. Every jQuery function returns a jQuery object, and that is how it works. This is a crucial part of jQuery's magic.

If you want to access the underlying element, you have three options...

1. Do not use jQuery
2. Use `[0]` to reference it
3. Extend jQuery to do what you want...

   ```
   $.fn.child = function(s) {
       return $(this).children(s)[0];
   }
   ```

Comment: Ah ha! That was it. I was expecting the img element (trying to reference its 'src' property) instead of the jQuery object. Now I'll just use 'attr()' to get at the 'src' property.

Comment: Thanks for 3) as well. I might consider doing that. :)

Comment: No. If I use for example `find("div")[0]` I will not get `div` as a jQuery object. I will get `div` as HTMLElement. To get `div` as jQuery object one has to use `.eq(0)`, as Greg said below.

Answer (score 135):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
$(this).children('img').eq(0);
```

this will give you a jquery object containing the first img element, whereas

```
$(this).children('img')[0];
```

will give you the img element itself.

Comment: Note that using find as in the first answer will give you all descendant elements, whereas child will give you only direct children.

Comment: From [jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/children/): `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe in this way?

```
$('img', this)[0]
```

Comment: This will not necessarily select the direct child and, just as the accepted answer, this will return the element, not the jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

You can target the first child element with just using CSS selector with jQuery:

```
$(this).children('img:nth-child(1)');
```

If you want to target the second child element just change 1 to 2:

```
$(this).children('img:nth-child(2)');
```

and so on..

if you want to target more elements, you can use a for loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= $(this).children().length; i++) {
    let childImg =  $(this).children("img:nth-child("+ i +")");
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not `jQuery`, as the question asks for, but natively (i.e., no libraries required) I think the better tool for the job is `querySelector` to get a single instance of a selector:

```
let el = document.querySelector('img');
console.log(el);
```

For all matching instances, use `document.querySelectorAll()`, or for those within another element you can chain as follows:

```
// Get some wrapper, with class="parentClassName"
let parentEl = document.querySelector('.parentClassName');
// Get all img tags within the parent element by parentEl variable
let childrenEls = parentEl.querySelectorAll('img');
```

Note the above is equivalent to:

```
let childrenEls = document.querySelector('.parentClassName').querySelectorAll('img');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<title>

    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<body>




<!-- <asp:LinkButton ID="MoreInfoButton" runat="server" Text="<%#MoreInfo%>" > -->
 <!-- </asp:LinkButton> -->
<!-- </asp:LinkButton> -->

<br />
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<div>
<a><span id="imgDownArrow_0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " runat="server"> MoreInformation</span></a>
<div id="parent" class="dataContentSectionMessages" style="display:none">
    <!-- repeater1 starts -->
        <!-- <sc:text field="Event Description" runat="server" item="<%#Container.DataItem %>" /> -->
            <ul  >
                <li ><h6><strong>lorem</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>An assigned contact who knows you and your lorem analysis system</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Internet accessible on-demand information and an easy to use internet shop</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Extensive and flexible repair capabilities at any location</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Full Service Contracts</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Maintenance Contracts</strong></h6></li>
            </ul>
    <!-- repeater1 ends -->
</div>
</div>
<div>
<a><span id="imgDownArrow_0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " runat="server"> MoreInformation</span></a>
<div id="parent" class="dataContentSectionMessages" style="display:none">
    <!-- repeater1 starts -->
        <!-- <sc:text field="Event Description" runat="server" item="<%#Container.DataItem %>" /> -->
            <ul  >
                <li ><h6><strong>lorem</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>An assigned contact who knows you and your lorem analysis system</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Internet accessible on-demand information and an easy to use internet shop</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Extensive and flexible repair capabilities at any location</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Full Service Contracts</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Maintenance Contracts</strong></h6></li>
            </ul>
    <!-- repeater1 ends -->
</div>
</div>
<div>
<a><span id="imgDownArrow_0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " runat="server"> MoreInformation</span></a>
<div id="parent" class="dataContentSectionMessages" style="display:none">
    <!-- repeater1 starts -->
        <!-- <sc:text field="Event Description" runat="server" item="<%#Container.DataItem %>" /> -->
            <ul  >
                <li ><h6><strong>lorem</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>An assigned contact who knows you and your lorem analysis system</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Internet accessible on-demand information and an easy to use internet shop</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Extensive and flexible repair capabilities at any location</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Full Service Contracts</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Maintenance Contracts</strong></h6></li>
            </ul>
    <!-- repeater1 ends -->
</div>
</div>
<div>
<a><span id="imgDownArrow_0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " runat="server"> MoreInformation</span></a>
<div id="parent" class="dataContentSectionMessages" style="display:none">
    <!-- repeater1 starts -->
        <!-- <sc:text field="Event Description" runat="server" item="<%#Container.DataItem %>" /> -->
            <ul  >
                <li ><h6><strong>lorem</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>An assigned contact who knows you and your lorem analysis system</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Internet accessible on-demand information and an easy to use internet shop</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Extensive and flexible repair capabilities at any location</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Full Service Contracts</strong></h6></li>
                <li ><h6><strong>Maintenance Contracts</strong></h6></li>
            </ul>
    <!-- repeater1 ends -->
</div>
</div>




</asp:Repeater>


</body>
<!-- Predefined JavaScript -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>

 $(function () {
        $('a').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().children('.dataContentSectionMessages').slideToggle();
        });
    });

    </script>


</html>
```

Comment: $(function () {
        $('a').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().children('.dataContentSectionMessages').slideToggle();
        });
    });                          this query will help to get the child item of a parent